# What is the scope of this attribute declared within this method?

Tags: python

Given this hypothetical function:

```
class testClass():
    def test(self):
        self.number = 0

        def add():
            self.number += 1
            return
        
        add()
        return
```

Is the scope of the attribute 'number' only restricted inside the 'test' method or can it be accessible within the entire class?

Comment: It's being assigned to `self`, it's an attribute of the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `number` can be accessible within the entire class.
Example:

```
class testClass():

    def test(self):
        self.number = 0

        def add():
            self.number += 1

        add()
    def test2(self):
        self.number += 1
        print(self.number)

m = testClass()
m.test()
m.test2()
```

The output is:

```
2
```

And of course, as jonrsharpe said, the `number` attribute is different for each instance of the class, it is not the same to all, meaning change one won't change the other.

Answer (score 0):

Scope does not apply, because `number` is not a variable, but the name of an attribute attached directly to whatever object `self` refers to. As such, it's accessible from that object and that object alone, no matter where a reference to that object exists.

(Or rather, every object potentially has a `number` attribute, depending on whether the attribute was set. Instance attributes aren't necessarily associated with the *type* of an object in any way.)

Answer (score -1):

The class method `test` can be accessed from anywhere in the class, because it has the `self` parameter in the parenthesis.

The add function within the test method can access anything from within the scope for the test method. and it can also access anything else from the whole class if you use the self keyword.

Comment: It isn't wrong what you said, it is just not an answer to his question.